# IIFE arrow function assigned to variables is not working

Tags: javascript

IIFE can be achieved when dealing with function expression. One rule is that everything after `=` sign is an expressien so below code works

```
const iife = function() { return 5 }(); // iife = 5
```

Why is that this is not working?

```
const iife = () => 5() or () => { return 5 }();
```

Why in case of arrow function I need to use parantheses to make it work?

```
const iife = (() => 5)() or (() => { return 5 })()
```

Isn't just `() => 5` or `() => { return 5 }` also an expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is that this is not working?
>
> `const iife = () => 5() or () => { return 5 }();`

In the former, JS interprets it as you trying to call a function named `5` and return its return value.

In the latter, JS interprets you trying to call an object as a function `{ return 5 }` and returning its return value.

Similarly, when calling an IIFE declared with `function`, curly braces are required. `function a() { return 5 }()` will not work, but `(function a() { return 5 })()` will.

It is necessary to wrap the two in brackets so the whole expression is interpreted as a function when called.

Comment: Oh man, you are right, I did not notice that I'm immediately returning value with the arrow function. Thanks